# Check if a string contains only a date, no timestamp

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to detect if a string contains a date without a timestamp. The date and timestamp can be in different formats.

I tried parsing the strings with python-dateutil, but it returns a datetime instance which contains a timestamp.

```
import dateutil.parser

print(dateutil.parser.parse("2020-01-01"))
print(dateutil.parser.parse("2020-01-01 01:24:37 UTC"))
```

returns

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020-01-01 01:24:37+00:00
```

Comment: I'm assuming you could exclude any string with spaces in it.  That would get you most of the way there.

Comment: A little hacky, but I'd suggest using the `default` parameter with different values for the time.  If the result has the defaults you specified, you know there was nothing in the string input that overrode those specific defaults.  (Do it twice with different defaults so you know that it didn't just happen to have the same value as the first one you tried.)

Comment: Given the samples you've shown then: *your_string.split()[0]* will reveal the date component. If there are any other tokens then you can deduce that there's something in addition to the date. After that it gets more complicated because you can't always determine whether a date is in DD-MM-YYYY or MM-DD-YYYY format

Comment: I believe the point of using `dateutil` is to be able to handle stuff like `"the first of January, 2001"`.  Trying to second-guess it with splits and regexes seems like it would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex for that purpose, since your input is a string

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$')
first = '2020-01-01'
second = '2020-01-01 01:24:37 UTC'
third = '2020-13-01'

if pattern.match(first):
    print('First is valid date')
else:
    print('First is invalid')

if pattern.match(second):
    print('Second is valid date')
else:
    print('Second is invalid')

if pattern.match(third):
    print('Third is valid date')
else:
    print('Third is invalid')
```

Which outputs:

```
First is valid date
Second is invalid
Third is invalid
```

**Regex explanation**:

- ^ and $ to delimiter start and end of string
- \d{4} to allow 4 digits
- (0?[1-9]|1[012]) will allow 1 or 2 digit month ranging from 1/01 to 12
- (0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) will search for 01 to 09, 10 to 19 or 20 to 29, and 30 or 31